# Add a row to dataframe and relabel the row name

Tags: r

I want to add a row to the `kirp` dataframe and name the row as `sample`

```
kirp[nrow(kirp) + 1,] <- "KIRP")
rownames(tail(kirp, n=1)) <- "sample"
```

Traceback:

```
Error in rownames(tail(kirp, n = 1)) <- "sample" : 
  could not find function "tail<-"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rbind`

```
rbind(dat, sample='KIRP')
#          X1   X2   X3   X4
# some      a    d    g    j
# row       b    e    h    k
# names     c    f    i    l
# sample KIRP KIRP KIRP KIRP
```

This is a special case, because normally a `data.frame` is `rbind`ed with appropriate column values.

```
rbind(dat, sample=data.frame(X1='KIRP', X2='foo', X3='bar', X4='baz'))
#          X1  X2  X3  X4
# some      a   d   g   j
# row       b   e   h   k
# names     c   f   i   l
# sample KIRP foo bar baz
```

To follow your idea you can use `nrow(dat)` again, since the error tells you there is no `` `tail<-` `` function.

```
dat[nrow(dat) + 1, ] <- 'KIRP'
rownames(dat)[nrow(dat)] <- 'sample'
dat
#          X1   X2   X3   X4
# some      a    d    g    j
# row       b    e    h    k
# names     c    f    i    l
# sample KIRP KIRP KIRP KIRP
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c("a", "b", "c"), X2 = c("d", "e", "f"), 
    X3 = c("g", "h", "i"), X4 = c("j", "k", "l")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("some", 
"row", "names"))
```